# system is returning error 127 when called from c++ in linux

Tags: android, linux, system

The command "**am start -n packagename/.activityname**" has to be run in adb shell and is to be included in C++ program

I added the line **system("am start -n packagename/.activityname")** in my C++ program and when the program is run in adb shell,
the system command is returning error code 127 and the shell command is not running

compiler used : **arm-linux-none-gnueabi-g++**

Its working when i used the g++ compiler

Is the problem with the compiler or with the path?

Answer (score 2):

system() will not, in fact, work properly from programs with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges on systems on which /bin/sh is bash version 2, since bash 2 drops privileges on startup linux.die.net/man/3/system

Instead of system i used **execl("/system/bin/sh","sh","test.sh")**

where test.sh has **am start -n packagename/.activityname** and it works

Comment: The call of `execl` is wrong. The last argument must be `NULL`. Thus, it should be `execl("/system/bin/sh","sh","test.sh",NULL)`.