# Calling shell script from C++

Tags: linux, bash, shell

A shell script test.sh is called from C++ code by the command **execl("/system/bin/sh","sh","test.sh")**

After the execution of shell script i need to get back the control to C++, but the shell script is just exiting not executing the next instructions in C++ code

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The link is dead, Any other resource you would recommend?

Comment: Google gives [this](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf). And of course, [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) or `man syscalls` on your Linux PC. But you need several days of reading time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `fork` to create a child process before you `exec`:

```
pid_t pid;
if((pid = fork()) == 0)
    execl("/system/bin/sh","sh","test.sh");
int status;
waitpid(pid, &status, 0); // wait for child process, test.sh, to finish
```

Comment: or simply wait(&status)

Comment: (pid = fork()) > 0 will be true for the parent process, for the child one it will be zero.

Comment: @BorisDavidov Well spotted, thanks! :d

Answer (score 1):

With the `exec` family of functions, your process *becomes* the newly executed process, meaning everything about the original process is lost.

What you need to use is the [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) function which creates a separate process and waits for it to complete and continues the execution.

Comment: system() is returning error code 127 when called from a C++ program in linux. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380594/system-is-returning-error-127-when-called-from-c-in-linux
Because of that i used exec() family, is it possible to retrieve original process by creating a child process

Comment: yes you can `fork` a new process and do `exec` on it, which is what the `system` does anyway.

Comment: Did you try `system` like this: `system("sh test.sh")`?

Comment: yes you can use the `wait` and `waitpid` functions: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html

Comment: Yes i used system("sh test.sh") but still didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
System("sh test.sh")
```

It works for me, as earlier I was using only `system("test.sh")` and it created an issue, sometimes it executes properly and sometimes it returns no results.