# C++ code on Android - execl() function call failure

Tags: android, c++, linux, shell

The Story - I got a script file on a rooted Android Wear device and I want to run it with my c++ code.

First I tried this `int ret = system(/system/bin/sh /full/path/a.sh)`, it turned out that every time `system()` return with code 127 - command not exists error.

I found this workaround here: [system is returning error 127 when called from c++ in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380594/system-is-returning-error-127-when-called-from-c-in-linux) and I do as @Nikhilendra said:

`int ret = execl("/system/bin/sh","/system/bin/sh","/full/path/a.sh",(char*)NULL)`

Now my c++ code crash at this line every time, even without return value, so I cant get any error code on this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT1**:
The script a.sh itself runs correctly.

**EDIT2**:
My question can be understood as a follow-up of [system is returning error 127 when called from c++ in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380594/system-is-returning-error-127-when-called-from-c-in-linux)

Comment: Nikhilendra did it with three parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [system is returning error 127 when called from c++ in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380594/system-is-returning-error-127-when-called-from-c-in-linux)

Comment: @greenapps Actually this is the correct way, Nikhilendra didn't give a complete arguments list.

Comment: The `execl` call replaces the current process image with a new process image. Is this intended?

Comment: @MartinZabel  The first argument is the full path of executable, the rest is the actual command which is separated into pieces. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl

Comment: @MartinZabel I am not sure about the process issue but what I am trying to do here is just execute `ps` and get the output of `ps`, which is implemented in a.sh............. And yes I have tried `system("ps")`, which also return code 127

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one of the `exec` functions to mimic the `system` call, you have to fork a new child process first because the current process (image) is replaced by the one given in the `exec` call. That is, the `exec` will only return, if it failed.

I can't say, if the `fork` system call works on Android. But, you can check the `exec` call with this little example. I actually tested it on a Linux machine. **EDIT**: You may have to change the path of `sh` to `/system/bin/sh`.

The content of `a.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World."
```

The content of the C++ test program (called it `exec_test`).

```
extern "C" {
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
}
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  execl("/bin/sh","sh","./a.sh",NULL);
  // execl only returns if it failed
  std::cout << "errno: " << errno << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ ./exec_test
Hello World.
```